# Reboot Cycle with Ubuntu Server 10.04.02 on Install

Tags: 10.04, server

Trying to install Ubuntu Server 10.04.02 on a Dell PowerEdge 2600, and I get stuck in a reboot cycle after installation (which prevents using the server).  No obvious reasons for it.  Anyone run into this before?

Comment: We need more information to be of any help. For instance: do you get past grub? Depending on the answer you either get a solution on repairing/reinstalling grub or other questions. Please elaborate on what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The hardware RAID card I have in the system doesn't have pre-loaded drivers for the card, i'll have to load them manually.

It'll be tricky, but I'll sort it out eventually.